# Use NOT Equal condition in sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I want to fetch orders that have a “Received” (ActivityID = 1) activity but not a “Delivered” (ActivityID   = 4) activity on orders table.  i.e orders that are received but not deliverd yet.

my query is

```
SELECT OrderID FROM tblOrderActivity
where (tblOrderActivity.ActivityID = 1 AND tblOrderActivity.ActivityID != 4)  
GROUP BY OrderID
```

it is not returning desired result. 
result should be orderID 2 and 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't really make sense. Grouping happens after `WHERE` clause, so you're basically getting all orders that have `ActivityID ==`1 (because if activity Id is `1` there it's always not equal to `4`).

After `WHERE` clause is applied you end up with following rows:

```
OrderID ActivityID  
1   1   
2   1   
3   1   
4   1
```

And these are the orders you group. No more condition is evaluated.

If `4` is the highest possible `ActivityID` you could do following:

```
SELECT OrderID 
FROM tblOrderActivity 
GROUP BY OrderID 
HAVING MAX(ActivityID) < 4
```

`HAVING` condition is applied after grouping, which is what you want.

Comment: I already did? It groups by `OrderId` and returns only those orders that have `MAX(ActivityID)` lower than 4.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Group by` is needed here. You can use a `Subquery` to find he order's which is not delivered. Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Yourtable a
WHERE  a.ActivityID = 1
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   yourtable b
                       WHERE  a.OrderID = b.OrderID
                              AND b.ActivityID = 4)
```